# How do I make my javascript continue execution after a page load?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to buff up my scripting skills and decided to try rigging a simple polling website. I want to be able to click a radio button, click the submit button, and then page back after the confirmation page loads. So far my code is this:

```
function vote(callback){
    // click radio button
    document.getElementsByName("qp_v273073")[0].click();
    // click vote button
    document.getElementsByName("qp_b273073")[0].click();
    callback();
}

vote(function(){        
    window.history.back();
});
```

The problem is that my code never pages back after the confirmation page loads. I assume that this is because the console refreshes every page load, how do I fix this?

Comment: Your code cannot keep running after navigating to another page -- once your page is gone, the scripts associated with the page are also gone. Instead, you need to use AJAX to send your form data without loading a new page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the submit loads a new page which has it's own JavaScript context, your `click()` statement (for the button) basically leaves your page and everything after won't be executed. I'm not sure how much influence you have over the page, but I see two relatively easy solutions.

1. Submit the form to an `iframe` on the same page to avoid leaving it
2. Submit the form via AJAX and discard the response